# Python Script - Not Iterating - Loop - STUCK

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Sadly, I have very little knowledge of python and had someone help me with a script.

I need to change an O (refering to an oxygen) in an xyz file to either an Ob (Oxygen bulk) or Ow (Oxygen water).

In the definitions.txt file:

```
1-258
259-795
```

1-258 - this refers to the first 1-258 atoms, if there's an O within these file, then it should be Ob
259-795 this refers to the 259-795 atoms, if there's an O within these file, then it should be Ow

- Only problem is that this needs to be done for 30000 iterations
- I keep getting this error

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  test.py, line 47, in 
  natoms= int(xyz[0].split()[0])
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1-258'
- Any advice on how to figure this out will be greatly appreciated!!!

SCRIPT:

```
*!/usr/bin/env python*

import numpy as np
from sys import argv,exit
from itertools import chain
from math import sqrt
from collections import defaultdict

def get_coordinates(coordinates):
x = float(coordinates.split()[1])
y = float(coordinates.split()[2])
z = float(coordinates.split()[3])
return x,y,z

*Calculate distance between 3 (x,y,z) points*

def vector_distance((x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2)):
dist = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2-z1)**2)
return dist

def group_to_range(group):
group = ''.join(group.split())
sign, g = ('-', group[1:]) if group.startswith('-') else ('', group)
r = g.split('-', 1)
r[0] = sign + r[0]
r = sorted(int(__) for __ in r)
return range(r[0], 1 + r[-1])

*Expand and sort the list of numbers*

def rangeexpand(txt):
ranges = chain.from_iterable(group_to_range(__) for __ in txt.split(','))
return sorted(set(ranges))
return range(r[0], 1 + r[-1])

*Expand and sort the list of numbers
def rangeexpand(txt):
ranges = chain.from_iterable(group_to_range(__) for __ in txt.split(','))
return sorted(set(ranges))
Usage
create 'defnitions.txt in your directory and add the atom numbers of the
bulk oxygens on the first line and the water oxygens on the second line
e.g
1-45,56,58
46-55,57,59-60*

xyz = open(argv[1],'r').read().splitlines()

definitions=open("definitions.txt",'r').read().splitlines()

bulk=rangeexpand(definitions[0])

water=rangeexpand(definitions[1])

natoms= int(xyz[0].split()[0])

ntrajs=len(xyz)/(natoms+2)

fout=open(argv[1]+"_edited","w")

for i,j in enumerate(xyz):

    if int(j.split()[0])==natoms:

            fout.write("{0}\n".format(j))

            fout.write("{0}\n".format(xyz[i+1]))

    if i+1 in bulk:

            fout.write("{0}-B {1} {2} {3}".format(j.split()[0],j.split()

[1],j.split()[2],j.split()[3]))

    if i+1 in water:

            fout.write("{0}-W {1} {2} {3}".format(j.split()[0],j.split()

[1],j.split()[2],j.split()[3]))
```

Comment: You have to correct formatting. Python requires indentations and specific coding style you simply ignored. This example is illegible.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `str.split` is to split on whitespace. If you want to split by another character/string (`'-'` in your case) you need to explicitly provide it as an argument when calling the method.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Please can you suggest what needs to be specified to spilt?

Comment: @user.17 I told you in my post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete novice and don't know how to fix this.